# How to submit form using REST API for Django backend with CSRF enabled?

Tags: django, django-csrf

I'm trying to submit form to Django Web app using Java Rest Client. It doesn't work at all, I have no idea why.

- I was able to login using my client.
- I took csrftoken and sessionid cookies from login response
- I do submit form and provide `csrfmiddlewaretoken=cookies.csrftoken.value`
- I send csrftoken and sessionid cookies along with request.

DJango backed doesn't recognise me and redirects to login. Why?

I managed to figure out that for GET requests I need to send only `sessionid` cookie. DJango redirects to login if Cookie 'csrftoken' is sent along with GET request.

What do I do wrong? It should be so trivial...

Here is my code, it works for login

```scala
// POST login form
def login() = {
    val accessToken = getAccessToken(Http(s"$baseUrl/accounts/login/").asString) // get csrf token from DJango
    val response =
      Http(s"$baseUrl/accounts/login/")
        .postForm(Seq(
          "username" -> username,
          "password" -> password,
          "csrfmiddlewaretoken" -> accessToken.csrftoken.getValue, // pass it here
          "next" -> "/"
        ))
        .cookie(accessToken.csrftoken)
        .asString

    getAccessToken(response) // get new sessionid, csrf token from cookies
  }
```

Here is a code that can GET page after login

```scala
// accessToken -> tokens returned after login POST
def getDir(accessToken: CookiesAndHeaders, hdfsPathDirParent: String): Unit = {
    val req = Http(s"$baseUrl/filebrowser/view=$hdfsPathDirParent")
      .cookie(accessToken.sessionid)
     // it fails if csrf token is provided. Redirects to login page....
     // works well with session token
    val response = req.asString

    println(response.code) // 200 yahoo!
    println(response.body) // page body! looks good
```

Now I try to submit form...

```scala
al req = Http(s"$baseUrl/filebrowser/mkdir?next=/filebrowser/view=$hdfsPathDirParent")
      .postForm(Seq("name" -> hdfsDirName,
        "path" -> hdfsPathDirParent,
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken" -> accessToken.csrftoken.getValue
      ))
      .cookie(accessToken.csrftoken)
      .cookie(accessToken.sessionid)
```

It doest' work... Backend redirects me to login page 
Why...

Comment: Use POST instead of GET

Comment: I do, it doesn't work